# How to set/pass WCF Action name to the Biztalk ESB using LoadGen

Tags: biztalk

We have WCF web service defined with 6 Operations with the single endpoint. This service is created by using "BizTalk WCF service publishing wizard". Basically end user will send the message by calling the particular “WCF SOAP ACTION” of the service. BizTalk resolves the itinerary based on the “SOAP ACTION” using BRE resolver.

***Now the requirement is to do the load test with above service***

To generate load for the service, we are using LoadGen. But we are having technical challenge specifying the WCF Action(operation) name in LoadGen. Do anyone have any idea how can we do this?

FYI., In our implementation, BizTalk ESB resolves the itinerary based on the “WCF Action” using BRE resolver and not with message type. By using message type, we able to resolves the itinerary using BRE resolver. But the requirement is use WCF Action(operation) name and not the message type to resolve the itinerary in BiaTalk ESB, because multiple operation uses same message type but do different action.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks 
Sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

For WCF services `LoadGen` cannot create a custom action header for the SOAP action. For basic profile binding you may try to use `SOAPSection` and define `SOAPHeader` nodes. That would exclude the use of `WCFSection`. A better option would be to change the WCF service to accept any action `[OperationContract(Action="*")]`